# Making changes to the devise user controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have started using devise for my rails app, however i need to make some changes to the controller logic that devise has, my problem is that i assign users roles, and i want to put in  `params[:user][:role_ids] ||= []` in the update action so if all the roles are unchecked then it actually works.

whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super
  end
 def update
   #edit here
 end
end
```

and make sure you update your routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'users/sessions' }
```